# JavaScript single page application, how to display correct HTML after form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am writing an email client as a single page application using AJAX. I have a button that brings you to a form where a user can enter the required details to send an email which you can submit using a button. What I want to have happen is **upon submitting an email, be brought to the user's sent mailbox**, but currently it always routes to the default inbox view. I believe this is because of the way I have a DOMContentLoaded event listener set up:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);

  // By default, load the inbox view
  load_mailbox("inbox");
});
```

This listener simply sets up the navigation buttons and sets the default mailbox. The load_mailbox function is a simple function that takes in a string of the desire mailbox to see and manipulates the DOM accordingly. Here is my compose_email() function that is intended to handle showing the sending an email form and handling submission.

```
function compose_email() {

  // Show compose view and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#open-mail-view').style.display= 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

  // Clear out composition fields
  document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';

  // Handle sending an email, return to sent inbox after TODO: Not returning to sent inbox
  let form = document.querySelector('#compose-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    const recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value;
    const subject = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value;
    const body = document.querySelector('#compose-body').value;
    fetch('/emails', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          recipients: recipients,
          subject: subject,
          body: body
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    load_mailbox('sent'); //This is not working!!! What to do?
  });
}
```

**After submission, I want the user to be shown their sent mailbox, which is currently not happening**. This is presumably because the DOMContentLoaded listener immediately gets triggered and brought to the "inbox" mailbox.

**How can I go about having the user see the sent mailbox DOM content while still maintaing the inbox mailbox as a default (upon refresh, initially opening the site, etc..)?**

Comment: have you considered using a framework instead of rolling your own SPA framework?

Comment: @bryan60 I'm aware there are frameworks that could do this better but I'm learning javascript and wanted to write without a framework just to get some fundamentals down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form submission is causing a page reload because the default action isn't prevented.

Firstly, start capturing the event object:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) { ...
```

then

```
    ev.preventDefault();
```

(...and to be extra-sure)

```
    //...
    load_mailbox('sent');
    return false;
```

at the end of the handler (not in the promise callbacks)